# rmarkdown/knitr: How to format function output as code?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Here's a rmarkdown snippet:

````
#Is this even achievable?
```{r echo = FALSE, comment = ""}
install.package(mvbutils)
library(mvbutils)
make.usage.section("paste", env=asNamespace('base'))
```
````

As expected this (when knitred in RStudio to `pdf`) prints something along the lines of

```
paste(..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL)
```

Note the absence of the leading `##`, by default appended to function output but in this example switched off using the `comment` flag. Is it possible to further adapt the representation of that output such that it equates (code highlighting and all) to the output of:

````
```{r eval = FALSE}
paste(..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL)
```
````

I'm writing a howto and this would make life REALLY easy.

Comment: A start is to use the additional flag `comment = ""`, removing the leading `## ` - now for the code highlighting ...

Comment: Integrated the `comment` flag into the question now ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign code to a chunk via the `code` option. Then `formatR::usage()` returns the code to show the usage of a function. Putting them together:

````
```{r, code=formatR::usage('paste'), eval=FALSE}
```
````